# Selecting the radio button with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to fetch data and trigger some automatic buying process with the following website. https://www.klwines.com/
Was using "puppeteer" methods with NodeJS to process the script. According to the following screenshot provided, I got stuck with an issue where I cannot select one of the a radio button from the list since all radio buttons having the same id. What I am trying to do is just trying to select the last radio button from the following list and then trigger he button shown in the image. I was using the following NodeJS code with the help of puppeteer.

```
await page.waitForNavigation();
await page.waitForSelector('[name="continue"]');
const radio = await page.evaluate("table tr:nth-child(4) > td > input[type=radio]")
radio.click()
```

Please note that the page variable is defined as the following.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
const page = await browser.newPage();
```

If someone can help with this to find a way that would be really great full.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way;

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


exports.yourStatus = async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://www.klwines.com/');

    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {


        function cleanData(element) {

            const items = element.getElementById('Shepmente_0__shepmentewayCode');
             return [...items].map(item => {

            console.log(item)

        });

        }


    return data;

};
```